# Multhreading with updates to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, concurrency, cron

I need to evaluate around 80k rows of data every day at 11am, and I hope to accomplish it within a few minutes.

I used multithreading that uses select_for_update() of Django that gets one row at a time, updates it, and then gets a new row.

The problem is, there is an issue where the counter increases too fast having the assumption that there are times where the row gets evaluated twice.

Here is my current code block:

```
while True:
        with transaction.atomic():
            user_history = UserHistory.objects.select_for_update().filter(is_finished=False).first()
            if user_history:
                user = UserProfile.objects.filter(id=user_history.user_profile_id).first()
                card_today = CardToday.objects.filter(id=user_history.card_today_id).first()
                rewarded_value = 0
                if user_history is item1:
                    if card_today.item1 > card_today.item2:
                        rewarded_value = card_today.item2/card_today.item1 + 1
                elif user_history is item2:
                    if card_today.item2 > card_today.item1:
                        rewarded_value = card_today.item1/card_today.item2 + 1

                user.coins += float(user.coins) + rewarded_value # the value increases too high here

                user.save()
                user_history.save()
            else
                break
```

This is the model for Card Today:

```
class CardToday(models.Model):
   item1 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   item2 = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

This is the model for User History:

```
class UserHistory(models.Model):
   card_today = models.ForeignKey(CardToday, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   answer_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   is_finished = models.BooleanField(default=False) // checks whether the card has already been evaluated.
```

rewarded value's computation is as follows:

```
rewarded_value = majority/minority + 1
```

majority and minority switches depending on which item has a greater value.

Each user_history can only choose between item1 or item2.

After a certain amount of time has passed, the code will evaluate which item has been picked on a CardToday.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

The framework I'm using is Django, and I have a cron job running from the library django-cron.

Comment: What does `doSomething` do? If the output is possible to get as the result of a DB query you may be able to do the update in one query

Comment: @IainShelvington, I'll look into your idea, but updating the user table and updating the user_history table has to still be done separately right?

Comment: Yes, they have to be updated separately but it's possible that you only need 2 DB calls. Can you share what `doSomething` is doing?

Comment: @IainShelvington, I added the edit.

Comment: Can you share your models and the `card_today_query_<x>` and `item<x>` variables? It may be easier if you explain exactly what the purpose of this update is

Comment: @IainShelvington, Hi, I modified the post with your requested changes.